# Sequence of functions tending to zero in L^2

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, banach-spaces, limits-and-convergence, counterexamples

Let us consider a sequence of functions $f_n : (0,1)\times (0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ in $L^2((0,1)\times (0,1))$ satisfying the following condition:
$$
 \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int_{1/j}^{1 - 1/j}\int_{0}^{1}|f_n(x,y)|^2 dx dy  = 0,
 $$
for all $j  = 1,2,\ldots$. However, this convergence is not necessarily uniform in $j$.

My question is: Does even if the convergence above is not uniform in $j$, we have
$$
 \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}|f_n(x,y)|^2 dx dy  = 0?
 $$

Otherwise, someone could find a counterexample?
I thank you in advance if anyone can answer.

Comment: $f_n(x,y)=n\chi_{(0,1/n)}(x)$

Comment: ah, $x$ should read as $y$ in RHS of this example

Comment: Thank you for the answer Fedor. It's a simple and nice counterexample.